# Github Actions Branch Name

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github Actions workflow where I am trying to use the branch name in my commit.

```
- name: Commit files
  run: |
    git config --local user.email github.actions@domain.com 
    git config --local user.name "username"
    git add -A
    if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD; then
      git commit -am "${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} ${{ env.TAG_NAME }} on ${{ env.CLUSTER_ENV }}"
      git push
    fi
```

My commit will fail if I do not have the branch name there. For some reason the output is the same as `TAG_NAME`.

I have also tried `${{ github.ref_name }}` and `${GITHUB_REF##*/}`, but the result is the same. How can I display the branch name in my commit message here?

I am starting the workflow from the command line in my local. Not sure if anymore information is needed.

Comment: Sometimes an easy way of solving this is by putting a bare `env` in a step, and then examining the output to see exactly what the available environment variables look like.

Comment: @larsks Thank you! I gave it a try, but it looks like the branch name is not here in the env output. I'll have to think of another way to get this.

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: There are some actions on the [Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=git+commit+push+) that can help you doing it as well nray (instead of using shell commands directly)

Comment: The Github action workflow was started by push to any branch based on tags, so that was why the branch name did not appear in the `env` output. The solution I followed was to instead create a new branch in my commit files step and then merge the branch.